# ALPC Windows NT API's?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-vista, ipc

I found that on Vista+ systems to connect to the new LPC ports aka ALPC you have to use new functions set:

```
     NtAlpcAcceptConnectPort NtAlpcCancelMessage NtAlpcConnectPort NtAlpcCreatePort   NtAlpcCreatePortSection NtAlpcCreateResourceReserve NtAlpcCreateSectionView   NtAlpcCreateSecurityContext NtAlpcDeletePortSection etc....
```

I was doing an intensive search but did not found any code examples from which i can learn how to use these functions.
So if someone have code examples or have application that is using them so i can reverse it please share.

Comment: If there is only an NT interface to a function that's usually indicative that it isn't for public consumption.

Comment: NtConnectPort is well documented just the new functions are not yet used a lot.

Comment: I can't find documentation of `NtConnectPort` on MSDN. Where is it documented?

Comment: Agh maybe i mistaked it with other NT function... anyways no one knows application that use these functions so i can analyse it ?

Comment: You are not supposed to use LPC directly. Use RPC locally instead. It uses LPC underneath.

Comment: This might serve as a good reference point - https://github.com/avalon1610/ALPC